# How to consume OSGI service from non-component class

Tags: java, servlets, service, osgi, aem

I have an object that is created during the course of a request, and I'd like that object to call a service. However, when the framework calls the bind methods, it binds to its own instance of the class, not the one I want to bind to.

```
public class A {
   final X x;
   final Y y;

   public A(Z z) {
        this.x = z.x;
        this.y = z.y;
   }

   public String doStuff() {
        //do stuff
        //call a service
   }
}

public class B extends RestAPIServlet {

    public String method(@SlingRequest SlingHttpServletRequest request, @SlingResponse SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        Z z = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getReader(), Z.class);
        return new A(z).doStuff();
    }
}

public class C extends TagSupport {

    public int doStartTag() {
        Z z = getZFromProperties();
        String res = new A(z).doStuff();
        pageContext.setAttribute("res", res);
        return super.doStartTag();
    }
}
```

Is there some way to call a service directly from A? Is there a preferred pattern for code reuse in the situation where you have a tag and a servlet performing the same work?

I've been asked not to make the tag/servlet implement a common interface to give A the service, nor to use a Supplier to give it access to the service through the tag/servlet.

Answer (score 2):

`BundleContext` can be retrieved using the `FrameworkUtil` helper class and that, in turn, can be used to get to the service that you want to use. Here is an example:

```
BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(A.class).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference serviceRef = bundleContext.getServiceReference(MyService.class.getName());
MyService myService = (MyService) bundleContext.getService(serviceRef);
```

Comment: Bit of a warning here: this method can have weird ripple effects that cause dependent components to not activate properly because SCR doesn't have the annotations to know what order things should be activated in. Likely better to pass in a reference.